# Arduino Mega 2560 + ESP8266 Problem with GET Request

Tags: esp8266, wifi, networking

I have an ESP8266 module connected to my Arduino Mega 2560. My goal is to send a GET request as below to the network:

```
api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vEB39F555B1B8295?tempData=cabbages
```

If that is successful, I will get the string "cabbages" along with the timestamp inside my Google Sheets. Note that I intend to change the string "cabbages" with many other data once this is working, but for now, just cabbages. Pasting the link above inside a web browser and pressing Enter seems work fine, but doing it automatically from inside Arduino with ESP8266 attached is somehow not as I expected.

After connecting to my home wifi I tried making a GET request to Google.com:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200);

  delay(3000);
  Serial2.write("AT\r\n");
  delay(3000);
  Serial2.write("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
  delay(3000);
  Serial2.write("AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n");
  delay(3000);

  Serial2.write("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"www.google.com\",80\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("AT+CIPSEND=80\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("User-Agent: curl/7.37.0\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("Host: www.google.com\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("Accept: */*\r\n\r\n\r\n");
}

void loop() 
{
  if (Serial2.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial2.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

And I get the response as follows, which is actually the Google home page:

```
AT
OK
AT+CWMODE=1
OK
AT+CIPMUX=0link is builded
Recv 80 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,1410:HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 08:49:38 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: NID=87=TS-mbT3JjN_vZQurH0M4e1tbNsgmSPF4ALY_ohGFUD6uz76RmbxY41AA_XtC75Wqxfcqu5v1lbLxy-tMa_yrn5-BHrxN7Hn6CeYVnEfG1bBsVd78Y6eHtJ0hOUQPIwaDM0_2wGPO52e7HQ; expires=Sat, 25-Mar-2017 08:49:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'ouzkV5yUFcO10gTUwL6wDQ',kEXPI:'1351569,1351634,1351727,3700317,3700398,4029815,4031109,4032678,4036509,4036527,4038012,4039268,4041303,4041899,4043492,4045841,4048347,4052304,4061155,4062186,4063879,4064904,4065786,4066707,4067342,4067860,4068550
+IPD,1410:,4069148,4069694,4069838,4069840,4069906,4070123,4070329,4071229,4071604,4071842,4072288,4072364,4072409,4072602,4072653,4072774,4073405,4073418,4073728,4073874,4073959,4074684,4074801,4074807,4075966,4075974,4076018,4076072,4076095,4076121,4076543,4076930,4076999,4077002,4077219,4077221,4077298,4078430,4078456,4078547,4078553,4078635,4079082,4079105,4079281,4079356,4079388,4079417,4079423,4079649,4079730,4079842,4079999,4080215,4080218,8300273,8502184,8503585,8504110,8504846,8505150,8505152,8505836,8506251,8506255,8506763,8506951,8507045,10200083,13500017',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_24'};google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(c){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,c,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,c,e,g);if(""!=a){b=new Image;var d=google.lc,f=google.li;d[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete d[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,c,e
+IPD,1410:,g){var d="",f=google.ls||"";if(!c&&-1==b.search("&ei=")){var h=google.getEI(e),d="&ei="+h;-1==b.search("&lei=")&&((e=google.getLEI(e))?d+="&lei="+e:h!=google.kEI&&(d+="&lei="+google.kEI))}a=c||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+d+f+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};})();var a=window.location,b=a.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=b){var c=a.href.substring(b+1);/(^|&)q=/.test(c)&&-1==c.indexOf("#")&&a.replace("/search?"+c.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g,"")+"&cad=h")};</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36
+IPD,1410:c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}</style><script></script><link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon"></head><body bgcolor="#fff"><script>(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo229.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}
if (!iesg){document.f&&docu
+IPD,1410:ment.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}
}
})();</script><div id="mngb">    <div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Search</b> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi">Images</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn">News</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/options/"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en" class=gb4>Web History</a> | <a  href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.com/" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div>    </div><center><br clear="all" id="lgpd"><div id="lga"><img alt="Google" height="92" src="/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png" style="padding:28px 0 14px" wid
+IPD,1410:th="272" id="hplogo" onload="window.lol&&lol()"><br><br></div><form action="/search" name="f"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top"><td width="25%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center" nowrap=""><input name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" type="hidden"><input value="en" name="hl" type="hidden"><input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp"><input name="biw" type="hidden"><input name="bih" type="hidden"><div class="ds" style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><input style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top" autocomplete="off" class="lst" value="" title="Google Search" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57"></div><br style="line-height:0"><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit"></span></span><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" onclick="if(this.form.q.value)this.checked=1; else top.location='/doodles/'" type="submit"></span></span></td><td class="fl sblc" align="left" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a><a href="/language_tools?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Language tools</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div style="margin:19px auto;text-alig
+IPD,1410:n:center" id="fll"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising Programs</a><a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a><a href="https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550" rel="publisher">+Google</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a><a href="http://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=MY&amp;prev=http://www.google.com.my/&amp;sig=__7K51G9uSjvgDR9Qb9AlXCF_YSJg%3D">Google.com.my</a></div></div><p style="color:#767676;font-size:8pt">&copy; 2016 - <a href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span></center><script>(function(){window.google.cdo={height:0,width:0};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b)var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body,a=d.clientWidth,b=d.clientHeight;a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log("","","/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI);})();})();</script><div id="xjsd"></div><div id="xjsi"><script>(function(){function c(b){window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src=b;document.getElementById("xjsd").appendChild(a)},0)}google.dljp=function(b,a){google.xjsu=b;c(a)};google.dlj=c;})();(function(){window.google.xjsrm=[];})();if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.ti
+IPD,1093:mers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp('/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.qP2M4Nmr0aA.O/m\x3dsb_he,d/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oEsHMah2R9GNISWp1OmWDR28RwSyQ','/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.qP2M4Nmr0aA.O/m\x3dsb_he,d/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oEsHMah2R9GNISWp1OmWDR28RwSyQ');google.xjs=1;}google.pmc={"sb_he":{"agen":true,"cgen":true,"client":"heirloom-hp","dh":true,"dhqt":true,"ds":"","fl":true,"host":"google.com","isbh":28,"jam":0,"jsonp":true,"msgs":{"cibl":"Clear Search","dym":"Did you mean:","lcky":"I\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky","lml":"Learn more","oskt":"Input tools","psrc":"This search was removed from your \u003Ca href=\"/history\"\u003EWeb History\u003C/a\u003E","psrl":"Remove","sbit":"Search by image","srch":"Google Search"},"nds":true,"ovr":{},"pq":"","refpd":true,"rfs":[],"scd":10,"sce":5,"stok":"hQ250lThE3z-O0zdRwiuIzzAggQ"},"d":{}};google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med('init');google.initHistory();google.med('history');}});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}
</script></div></body></html>CLOSED
```

However, when I try it with the actual URL I intend to use:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200);

  delay(3000);
  Serial2.write("AT\r\n");
  delay(3000);
  Serial2.write("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
  delay(3000);
  Serial2.write("AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n");
  delay(3000);

  Serial2.write("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"api.pushingbox.com\",80\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("AT+CIPSEND=135\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("GET /pushingbox?devid=vEB39F555B1B8295&tempData=cabbages HTTP/1.0\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("User-Agent: curl/7.37.0\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("Host: api.pushingbox.com\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial2.write("Accept: */*\r\n\r\n\r\n");
}

void loop() 
{
  if (Serial2.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial2.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

I get the following response:

```
AT
OK
AT+CWMODE=1
OK
AT+CIPMUX=0
OK
AT+CIPSTART=Accept: */*ERROR
ERROR
ERROR

+IPD,212:HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
CLOSED
```

The code is exactly the same except for the different URLs used, so what is causing the problem here? Why can't I send "api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vEB39F555B1B8295?tempData=cabbages" to the internet? Please help! :-/

Comment: All those string literals need wrapping in `F(...)` or you will be overflowing your precious RAM.

Comment: But "cabbages" is something I wish to change later. Isn't F(...) only for constant strings?

Comment: Yes, and 99.99% of that (all except the word "cabbages" and the content length value) is constant strings.

Comment: Hey @Majenko thanks for the tip. But I can't seem to compile right with the F(....) wrapping. :-/

Comment: Did you get this issues sorted? I have the same problem, yet I can "GET" to Thingspeak with the same code without any issues? When I copy the URL directly into my web browser it works, however, the timeout error occurs only when I make use of my Arduino the "Serial.print" the GET command. would like your feedback, thanks! EO

Answer (score 1):

I did notice you also changed

AT+CIPSEND=80\r\n

to

AT+CIPSEND=135\r\n

probably you send your request wrong or something?!?
(sorry I post this as answer but I didn't unlock comments yet)

Answer (score 0):

First you must check if the problem is on your side or not.
You call http://api.pushingbox.com and you send parameter which are "pushingbox?devid=vEB39F555B1B8295&tempData=cabbages"

When I glue them together
http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vEB39F555B1B8295&tempData=cabbages
and copy past this on my browser, I get an error with "Daily limit exceeded" with a status of 429 meaning "too many request".
So maybe there is a problem with the server?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```cpp
Serial2.write("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
```

to:

```cpp
Serial2.write("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n");
```

or:

```cpp
Serial2.write("AT+CWMODE=3\r\n");
```